# recursive callback over set of nodes

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback

I have a tree structure (jstree.js ) that is a list of DOM elements. For each element I check if it is a parent, select its children, and check there parent status, ...

I need to parse the tree elements into an array of objects.  If an element is a parent, it is given an additional property, as an array of its child object.  Those child objects are checked recursively.

Here is the basic structure I am trying to parse the list of DOM elements into. **This is the output I am looking for**

```
 [ {s:0,c:[ {s:1}, {s:2,c:[s:3]}, {s:4} ]} ]
```

Here is the basic recursive function:
I check the `type()` of the node.  If it is a parent I am trying to use a callback to recurse over the set of children.  If it is a child element, then I return the id attribute

```
 function Parse3(rootelem,OBJ,freduce) {
                function type(e){
                    //var e = new Element(root.id)
                    // return !e.isParent ? {'sibling':e.jstxt} : freduce( parent, cb)
                    if (!e.isParent){
                        console.log('- - - CHILD - - -', e.jstxt )
                        return {'sibling':e.jstxt}
                        }
                    if (e.isParent) {
                        console.log('- - - PARENT - - -', e.jstxt )
                        return freduce(OBJ, e, function(i){
                            for ( var i=0; i<e.numchildren; i++ ){
                                console.log('recurse',i ,' ', type( e.childElements[i]) );
                                type( e.childElement[i] )
                            }})
                    }
                }//close type
                return type(rootelem)
            }//Parse3
```

Next, (I got this to work with primitive types) But since I am dealing with methods I return a reduce function that holds the cb.

```
   function freduce(OBJ, e,cb){
        OBJ.push( {'sibling':e.jstxt, 'xml':[] }  )
        var obl= OBJ.length-1 == undefined ? 0 : OBJ.length-1
        OBJ[ obl ].xml.push( cb )
        return OBJ
       }
```

How do I iterate over the selected childnodes.  I am a little new to javascript and am not too sure about the callback logic that I am using to iterate over children.  Further, I am unsure about how to reduce the child property to an element object.

(In dealing with nested structure, I was able to get this to work with primitives (numbers).  Dealing with objects and iterating over the set of child elements is causing problems ...)

Any suggestion are appreciated!

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: its the array of objects listed... ill highlight to make it more clear

Comment: What is this `xml[]` about in your code, as it does not appear in your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to call `freduce` which only complicates things. You can create the `xml` property inside the type function without the whole call and callback pattern.

Also, you should try not to pass `OBJ` around: instead build it up from the recursive return value, up to the final return value: this is the way the caller gets the result:

```
function parse3(rootelem) {
    function type(e){
        var obj = {'sibling': e.jstxt};
        if (e.isParent){
            obj.xml = [];
            for (var i=0; i<e.numchildren; i++ ){
                obj.xml.push(type(e.childElement[i]));
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    return type(rootelem);
}
```

NB: You should better not name variables with all capitals, which is commonly used to denote constant primitive values. Also the first letter should not be capitalised, as that is mostly used for constructor/class names.

#### Some further improvements:

With the above code, the function `parse3` is in essence not different any more from the function `type`: they both take the same arguments and return the same kind of information.

Furthermore, you can iterate over the `childElement` list with a `map` function, or (if it is not a real Array), with the `Array.from` callback. Then it becomes nice also to do everything in one expression, making use of `Object.assign`:

```
function parse3(e) {
    return Object.assign ({sibling: e.jstxt},
        e.isParent ? { xml: Array.from(e.childElement, parse3) } : {});
}
```